# iOS push notification repeating # badge value

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, push-notification

I really don't know why/where to start debugging this issue. One of my users has an issue where the badge value number of push notifications that are received are repeating. For example, if he recevied a push notification and the badge # of 1, it will display 11 on the app icon. 2 -> 22, 3 -> 33.

I have confirmed that this isn't a server side issue (the jSON passed in has the correct badge #) and he is the only user who is having this issue.

I am wondering if this is a documented issue/edge case and if not, how can i start debugging this (given I can't reproduce it o multiple devices)?

Comment: As long as it push notification, badge number are handled from server only. Check badge field in your push notification message..